# No connection could be made On Asp.net Core Angular Webapi publish IIS

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, webapi

After publishing asp.net core web api on IIS I got this message

[image]

I have tried this code

```
  app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {


            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsDevelopment())
            {

             //Have tried this line
                //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);


                   spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        });
```

but it works fine when I manually run **ng serve** command (if I put the complete solution on deployment server)from clientApp folder.

Please help

Comment: What happens when you hit http://localhost:4200 directly?

Comment: simply its not listening